# SHA1 error when using brew install ruby-build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedora, linuxbrew

I was using Linuxbrew(which is a linux equivalent of homebrew) to install "ruby-build"

command used:- *brew install ruby-build*

and here is the error that i got,

```
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 2599afa039d2070bae9df6ce43da288b3a4adf97
Actual: 6d840506239fc0b47ad5c1b14bd5e3e0edbeaa60
Archive: /home/User1/.cache/Homebrew/makedepend-1.0.5.tar.bz2
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

Later I tried deleting the *makedepend-1.0.5.tar.bz2* file and run the above command again, still the error persists.

Comment: Run 'brew doctor'? Does that work on the linuxbrew?

Comment: yes but with a warning- `Warning: Your file-system on [["/"], ["/tmp"]] appears to be CaSe SeNsItIvE.
Homebrew is less tested with that - don't worry but please report issues.`